# How to call a Visualforce component to Javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I need to create a javascript where in if the save button is pressed it will show a confirmation pop up if the user want's to save it or no. Now my only problem is I don't know how to call a input field to the javascript function. For example I have this input field 
`<apex:inputField value="{!myVar.item.SPR_Price__c}">` How can I call it to the Javascript function?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an ID to your apex:inputField and then access it in javascript using

```
var spr_price= document.getElementById("input_spr_price");
```

You can then access your value using

```
spr_price.value
```

Comment: Hi @PierrickBrun. Well I already tried that but it does not work. The thing is my input field is. inside a <apex:form> then an <apex:pageBlock> then <apex:pageBlockSection>, then <Apex:Column>

Comment: Is your javascript button part of your visualforce page or is it called by a custom button ? Note that Salesforce adds prefix to the ID (eg. id="j_id0:j_id1:test") So you could want tu use document.querySelectorAll("[id$=test]") and iterate over the elements. Look at this JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BBaFa/2/

Comment: Also querySelectorAll doesn't work on IE 8 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Comment: Yes my javascript is part of the visualforce page and I will call it on the <apex:commandbutton onlick="Javascript function()">

Comment: Doesn't using <apex:commandbutton onlick="Javascript function({!myVar.item.SPR_Price__c})"> work ?